# With One Select Statement how To Get The Following Table Result

Tags: sql-server

In this the output need to get is that the value from the each id that should have only one value assign to that id(col1). if the same id has diff value no need to take that values and output.

Below is a sample table

Input Table `'Demo'`

```
col1   col2
100     A
100     A
100     A
100     A
101     A
101     B
102     A
102     B
102     B
102     C
```

Output

```
col1   col2
100    A
100    A
100    A
100    A
```

Comment: Teradata or SQL Server? Those are two very different database products.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Teradata? You've tagged both but they're different platforms.

Comment: yes it for learn process.

Comment: Why does have to be a single select statement? Seems overly contrived to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select d.*
from Demo d
where not exists (select 1 from Demo d1 where d1.col1 = d.col1 and d1.col2 <> d.col2);
```

Comment: this will get the result but I need to know is it possible to get in a solving with one select statement.

Comment: That _is_ one `select` statement. It's one `select` statement that includes a `where not exists` clause.